# Function with harmonic properties

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let $g(z)$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb R^n\setminus \{0\}$.
$$ \int_{B_R(0)}  |g(z)| dz \leq C_1 $$ for some constant $C_1$, and with $B_R (0)$ being the ball of radius $R$ centered at the origin. Outside the ball

$$|g(z)|\leq C_2 | z|^k ,\; \forall z\in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus B_R (0) .$$

Does it follow that
$$ \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}   g(\epsilon z+y) \exp(-\pi | z |^2) dz = g(y)\,? $$

If yes can you please give me a reference for the proof? Or if not give a counterexample.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: I try to see with the function $g(z) = 1/z$ as it has the properties.

Answer (score 0):

Without further assumptions on $g$ this is false. Take $g(x) = 0 $ for $x\neq 0$ and $g(0)=1$. Then $g$ is continuous in $\mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\}$ (in fact it is smooth there) but $g=0$ a.e. so $$\int_{\mathbb R^n} g(\varepsilon z) e^{-\pi \vert z\vert^2} \, dz = 0 \neq g(0) . $$

Comment: Say $g(z)$ is continuous everywhere in $R^n$ then?